# Generalisation of the functional equation f(xy) = f(x) + f(y)

Tags: real-analysis, logarithms, functional-equations

If I understand correctly (I am a high school student), when proving the existence of $\ln x$ in real analysis, we consider the functional equation 
$$ f(xy) = f(x) + f(y)$$
I understand that there are many questions on Stackexchange on this functional equation, but I was wondering whether anything interesting occurs when we consider 
$$f(xyz) = f(x) + f(y) + f(z)$$ or even $$f(xyz\dots) = f(x) + f(y) +f(z) + \dots$$
$\ln x$ seems to work for this too, but do any other functions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that any of these equations imply that $f(1)=0$ (for example, $f(xyz)=f(x)+f(y)+f(z)\implies f(1)=f(1^3)=3\times f(1)\implies f(1)=0$).  Use this observation to show that all your equations are essentially equivalent.

Comment: Hello and welcome to math.stackexchange! This is a natural question to ask. Here is a way to get to an answer: Note that if $f(xyz) = f(x) + f(y) + f(z)$ for all $x,y,z$, then by choosing $x = y = z = 1$ you obtain $f(1) = 3f(1)$ and thus $f(1) = 0$. Then the relation $f(xy) = f(x) + f(y) $ follows by setting $z = 1$. And of course if $f(xy) = f(x) + f(y)$ for all $x,y$, it follows that $f(xyz) = f(xy) + f(z) = f(x) + f(y) + f(z)$. Thus the two properties are in fact equivalent.

Comment: You want this to be continuous?  :-)

Comment: @lulu Assuming $1$ is in the domain.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt  Sure.  More strongly, here I'd imagine that the OP is only looking at the "nice" solutions.  We could, for example, take one of the discontinuous functions that satisfies $G(x+y)=G(x)+G(y)$.  and then define $f(x)=G(\log x)$.  But I expect the OP wants continuity or something like that.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Although I think it does seem interesting to consider discontinuous functions (if that leads to anything interesting, I would be delighted to hear more about it) I was primarily considering continuous functions for this question.

Answer (score 1):

There are two obvious solutions:

$f(x) = 0$

and

$f(x) = \log_b (x)$

I am not exactly sure, but this could be a possibility too:

Let $x = 2^{(p/q)} \cdot b$ with $b$ being not of the form $2^{(p/q)}$, then

$f(x) = p/q$

If $x$ is irrational, then $f(x)$ is not defined.

This function would be, of course, discontinues everywhere.

-

I might have found another possibility, but it is hard to turn it into a formula.

The required condition implies that $f(x^n) = n f(x)$. Let's now define the function for natural numbers:

If $x$ is prime, then $f(x) = 1$. Of course $f(1) = 0$. Now, by applying the rule above, we can get do any power of a prime. Any other composite number can be split into it's prime factors and therefore be deducted.

Now we can get to rational numbers as well. For example:

"What is $f(\frac{2}{3})$?" Answer: $f(9 \cdot \frac{2}{3}) = f(6)$ which leads to $f(9) + f(\frac{2}{3}) = f(6)$ and therefore $f(\frac{2}{3}) = 0$

Finally, $f(p/q) = f(p) - f(q)$, so this can be expanded to rational numbers as well.

Comment: You can use curly brackets with ^ to get the whole expression raised. Click edit if you want to see how.

Comment: Thank you for editing, I am fairly new to TeX and therefore unexperienced

Comment: You can sometimes click edit to see how other people have written to learn from them and there are also tutorials if you want to learn.

Comment: Here's a tutorial: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 1):

There is no way you can have

$$f(xy) = f(x)+f(y)$$

without having

$$f(xyz) = f(x)+f(y)+f(z)$$
since, treating $xy$ as one factor, we have:
$$f((xy)z) = f(xy)+f(z) = f(x)+f(y)+f(z)$$

In a similar way you can by induction show that for $n$ factors you can reduce down to $n-1$ factors and that the $2$ factor case is true.